# How to make the if else statement that will display the last satisfied statement

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and i want to display the last satisfied statement on this code.

```
   if (led.last.contains('SEAT: on'))...
     [const Icon(
      Icons.fingerprint,
      color: Colors.teal,
      size: 50,
   )]
   else if (led.last.contains('SEAT: off')) ...
    [const Icon(
      Icons.fingerprint,
      color: Colors.grey,
      size: 50,
   )
```

My goal is that the icon will not disappear when the conditional statements are not satisfied.

Comment: Could you get a more complete example of what you want? If I understood correctly, why not just invert your if...else if... block?

Comment: Please don't post duplicates of your existing questions.

Answer (score 1):

if you want just to change the color of the Icon according to a condition, you can do this :

```
Icon(
  Icons.fingerprint,
  color: led.last.contains('SEAT: on') ? Colors.teal: Colors.grey ,
  size: 50,
)
```